# React setstate on big and small states

Tags: reactjs

I have a state like this :

```
{
    textfield: '',
    data: [] //huge, used to render elements within the render()
}
```

When I want to update the `textfield` value (simple text input), I use `this.setState({ textfield: newValue });`. The problem is that there is some lag when I write a character in the field because it is re-rendering everything.

Is using `shouldComponentUpdate()` and deeply check my data object the only way to avoid re-rendering everything? Or is there a better/more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: Any code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am guessing its rerendering the entire component due to the state change on every key.

you could isolate your input element in a separate stateful component, hence only triggering a re-render on itself and not on your entire app.

So something like:

```
class App extends Component {    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <MyInput />
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MyInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {textfield: ""};
  }

  update = (e) => {
    this.setState({textfield: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.update} value={this.state.textfield} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I think that will do it, thing is it seems kinda odd to have to always create a 'smaller' component :/

Comment: the key is to reuse component logic, have a look at: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html  maybe it can help you